# Getting the font for a specified style

Tags: officer

If I load up the default word document in officer and look at the styles that are available:

```
library("officer")
my_doc <- read_docx()
styles_info(my_doc)
```

I can see the following styles are available:

```
  style_type            style_id             style_name is_custom is_default
1   paragraph              Normal                 Normal     FALSE       TRUE
2   paragraph              Titre1              heading 1     FALSE      FALSE
3   paragraph              Titre2              heading 2     FALSE      FALSE
4   paragraph              Titre3              heading 3     FALSE      FALSE
5   character      Policepardfaut Default Paragraph Font     FALSE       TRUE
6       table       TableauNormal           Normal Table     FALSE       TRUE
7   numbering         Aucuneliste                No List     FALSE       TRUE
8   character              strong                 strong      TRUE      FALSE
9   paragraph            centered               centered      TRUE      FALSE
10      table       tabletemplate         table_template      TRUE      FALSE
11      table Listeclaire-Accent2    Light List Accent 2     FALSE      FALSE
12  character           Titre1Car            Titre 1 Car      TRUE      FALSE
13  character           Titre2Car            Titre 2 Car      TRUE      FALSE
14  character           Titre3Car            Titre 3 Car      TRUE      FALSE
15  paragraph        graphictitle          graphic title      TRUE      FALSE
16  paragraph          tabletitle            table title      TRUE      FALSE
17      table       Professionnel     Table Professional     FALSE      FALSE
18  paragraph                 TM1                  toc 1     FALSE      FALSE
19  paragraph                 TM2                  toc 2     FALSE      FALSE
20  paragraph       Textedebulles           Balloon Text     FALSE      FALSE
21  character    TextedebullesCar    Texte de bulles Car      TRUE      FALSE
22  character         referenceid           reference_id      TRUE      FALSE
```

Is it possible for me to get the font for a given style. For example how would I go about getting the font associated with the `Normal` style?